# How to insert a table view inside access form?

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to insert a table having five columns and unlimited rows inside a Form. Have no idea about storage of these table values and how to insert it in a form.Thank u for ur help

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to include a subform on your form.

Microsoft has provided detailed information on how to use a subform here:

[Create a form that contains a subform](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-HA101872705.aspx)